# Get value from Request URL response data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Requested URL sent - https://www.example.com/detail.guest.html?ppc=FDE466920006DCEFA697BF982FC9C87C5B257ECB2230CBF4D6D6CA740C7B894D5795F70DED928ED3B00C1F3F77DF974DFD73882DEBDD7EC063B37DEB24CF655528FD911109C57961AE314C612772AADFD2E193D572E6F6C8E249A6DAA

Get below response data correctly as expected by 3rd party.

BookersID=250100000002;BookersTitle=Mr;BookersFirstName=test1;BookersLastName=test2

[image]

---

I want to extract "BookersID", "BookersTitle", "BookersFirstName", "BookersLastName" separately and display this value in input field.

**JS:**

```
var bookerID = data[0].BookersID;
var bookerTitle = data[0].BookersTitle;
var bookerFname = data[0].BookersFirstName;
var bookerLname = data[0].BookersLastName;
console.log("BookersID", bookerID);
console.log("BookersTitle", bookerTitle);
```

But getting error in display value.

Please let me know how to get the value in console log?

Thanks

Comment: please provide json data

Comment: That response is a string, not a JSON array. You need to parse it.

Comment: Are you getting the same response? "BookersID=250100000002;BookersTitle=Mr;BookersFirstName=test1;BookersLastName=test2" nothing else?

Comment: @AshokVishwakarma Please check attached image. I will get response like this.

Comment: The `_convert` function will work, just pass your response into the same as given in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get data from your xhr request. To do that you need to add callback function. (More info in [jQuery.get() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/))

```
$.get( endpoint, function( data ) { // add callback to handle response
 // ... parse data here
});
```

As I understand you need to parse data. It could be done by using `String.prototype.split` method and simple mapping.

```
console.log(data) // BookersID=250100000002;BookersTitle=Mr;BookersFirstName=test1;BookersLastName=test2
var parsed = data.split(';').map(part => ({ name: part.split('=')[0], value: part.split('=')[1] }));

console.log(parsed);
```

Output:

```
[
   {name: "BookersID", value: "250100000002"},
   {name: "BookersTitle", value: "Mr"},
   {name: "BookersFirstName", value: "test1"},
   {name: "BookersLastName", value: "test2"}
]
```

If you want to get data as an object:

```
var parsedObject = parsed.reduce(
    (obj, item) => Object.assign(obj, {[item.name]: item.value}) ,{});
// {BookersID: "250100000002", BookersTitle: "Mr", BookersFirstName: "test1", BookersLastName: "test2"}
```

Comment: Hi.. Pls check attached image. I will get response like this. Not sure whether we need to parse or directly get the string value. I need to get value from here (attached screenshot) in my comments. thanks

Comment: @TDG what is inside of your `data` variable?

Comment: Not sure.. on submit that encrypted url.. i will get this value as response. But not sure how to split and display in input field. I am too confused with "data" variable.

Comment: @TDG how do you submit it?

Comment: makeAjaxRequest( endpoint ) {
    if (typeof endpoint == 'undefined' || endpoint == '') return;
    return $.get(endpoint);
  }

Comment: Sure.. your code will work fine. But how to bring response strings into data variable? I struck in this area only.

Comment: @TDG check this now

Comment: @partyk.. thanks for your reply. All ok.. but, i want to insert BookersID value into input field.  $('.bookersIDInput').val(BookersID.value)  will it work?

Comment: @TDG `$('.bookersIDInput').val(parsedObject.BookersID)` should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you getting the same response you need to write a utility function to convert the same into an object

```
function _convert(responseString) {
  var _obj = {};

  responseString.split(";").forEach(function(pair){
     var _pairArr = pair.split("=");
     _obj[_pairArr[0]] = _pairArr[1];
  });

  reuturn _obj;
}

var responseString = "BookersID=250100000002;BookersTitle=Mr;BookersFirstName=test1;BookersLastName=test2";
var obj = _convert(responseString);

obj['BookersID']; // 250100000002
// or
obj.BookersID; // 250100000002
```

**Note:** This will only work if your response has exactly the same format as you have mentioned.

Comment: Hi.. Pls check attached image. I will get response like this. Not sure whether we need to parse or directly get the string value. I need to get value from here (attached screenshot) in my comments. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'BookersID=250100000002;BookersTitle=Mr;BookersFirstName=test1;BookersLastName=test2';
var data = {};
var parsed = str.split(';').map(part => { let x = part.split("="); data[x[0]] = x[1]; console.log(x) });
console.log(data)
```

Output:

```
{BookersID: "250100000002", BookersTitle: "Mr", BookersFirstName: "test1", BookersLastName: "test2"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to create your string into an object, which can then have its properties accessed

```js
const data = "BookersID=250100000002;BookersTitle=Mr;BookersFirstName=test1;BookersLastName=test2";

const dataObj = data.split(';').reduce((acc, kvp) =>
  ({
    ...acc,
    ...(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))(kvp.split('='))
  }), {});

console.log(dataObj);
// access properties:
console.log(dataObj.BookersID);
```